# Understanding function algorithm

Tags: swift, mkmapview

During study tutorial, i using function to show visible rect, containing all of annotations (on mapView) as it shown:

```
// 1
let rectToDisplay = self.treasures.reduce(MKMapRectNull) { (mapRect: MKMapRect, treasure: Treasure) -> MKMapRect in
// 2
let treasurePointRect =
MKMapRect(origin: treasure.location.mapPoint,
size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0)) 
return MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, treasurePointRect)
// 3
}
// 4
self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rectToDisplay, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(74, 10, 10, 10), animated: false)
```

Everything work, but I'm not understanding how exactly it working.

On third lane, we are doing following:

```
return MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, treasurePointRect)
```

Before that, we declare

```
mapRect: MKMapRect
```

So, mapRect does not have any initial value and suppose to not contain any values. Am i right?

How exactly MKMapRectUnion calculated, if mapRect have zero values? Is there any way i could look at every step of function using some kind of NSLog statement?

If you be so kind, please, explain me in details how that function work. As i understand, function try to make map Rect combining "zero" value map point and other mapPoint, with correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have understood everything correctly. as for your question

> How exactly MKMapRectUnion calculated, if mapRect have zero values?

apple docs says:

> If either rectangle is null, this method returns the other rectangle.
>   The origin point of the returned rectangle is set to the smaller of
>   the x and y values for the two rectangles. Similarly, the size and
>   width of the rectangle are computed by taking the maximum x and y
>   values and subtracting the x and y values for the new origin point.

how exactly that is being calculated, you can ask apple engineers or reverse engineer the mapkit. if the function does work fine then you don't have go to such length and divert from your real assignment.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but can you please provide me a link when i can read text from quote?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKMapRectUnion